# Mapping a Collection of Enums to a single varchar column

Tags: java, hibernate, collections, enums, mapping

In hibernate I need to map a Collection of Enums to a single varchar column (e.g. as a comma-separated list of enum values).

Answer (score 2):

You can create a Hibernate UserType where you set the value as comma separated String:

```
 public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement st, Object value, int index) throws HibernateException {
    try {
        if (null == value) {
            st.setNull(index, Types.VARCHAR);
        } else {
            st.setString(index, toCommaSeparated((Set<Enum>) value));
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new HibernateException(String.format("Exception while stringifing '%s'", value), e);
    }

}

private String toCommaSeparated(Set<Enum> inputSet) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String delim = "";
    for (Enum current : inputSet) {
        sb.append(delim).append(current.name());
        delim = ",";
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

and you get it as an EnumSet:

```
    @Override
public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet rs, String[] names, Object owner) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
    String name = rs.getString(names[0]);
    if (rs.wasNull()) {
        return null;
    }

    try {
        Set<Enum<?>> retSet = EnumSet.noneOf(enumClass);
        if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(name)) {
            String[] values = name.split(",");
            for (String value : values) {
                Enum<?> current = getEnumValueFor(value);
                if (current != null) {
                    retSet.add(current);
                }
            }
        }
        return retSet;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new HibernateException("Exception getting object from comma separated string", e);
    }
}

private Enum<?> getEnumValueFor(String name) {
    for (Enum<?> current : enumClass.getEnumConstants()) {
        if (current.name().equals(name)) {
            return current;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

This implementation is just to give you the idea and it can certainly be improved or adapted to your needs. You can also find plenty of tutorial on how to create your own UserType and probably parametrize it with the Enum class you want to store.

Answer (score 1):

I really wouldn't do that, because it makes it impossible to query your data.

If you really want to do it, then just transform the collection into a string in the setter, and the string into a collection of enums into the getter. With Guava:

```
private String fooValues;

public EnumSet<Foo> getFoos() {
    EnumSet<Foo> result = EnumSet.noneOf(Foo.class);
    for (String fooAsString : Splitter.on(',').split(fooValues)) {
        result.add(Foo.valueOf(fooAsString);
    }
    return result;
}

public void setFoos(EnumSet<Foo> foos) {
    this.fooValues = Joiner.on(",").join(foos);
}
```

Comment: thnks, but I look for a facility from hibernate that do this convert.

Comment: In your solution String splitting is done in each getter call. Trying to refine performance results in synchronizing code between Set property and String property and all of these make code dirty.

Comment: You won't find one, because storing a Set of values in a single column is plain ugly. Store it in a separate table, and everything will be done by Hibernate.

Comment: I tend to this ugly solution to avoid an extra join that will affect performance.